# How to Implement Tree Structure Algorithm with levels in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, algorithm

I tried level 1 code but don't understand how to implement further levels and get user team, I need help in this...

Process:

- User A will create profile by direct register.
- If user register him self as direct then he is on the top level then user A will share ref link to join users then other user will be added in the team of user A as user B.
- If user B share ref link to anyone then that user will be added under user A as user C.
- In this way user A level will be 1.

I tried to complete level 1 and code is below. Need Help in all other levels upto 20 and how to get team of user A, B, C... N

Check below Image to understand tree structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEEef.png)

```
            $ref_code_value = Session::get('ref_code');
           
            if($ref_code_value) {
                $ref_user = User::where('ref_code', $ref_code_value)->first();
                if($ref_user) {
                    $direct_user = new DirectUser();
                    $direct_user-> user_id = $ref_user-> id;
                    $direct_user-> direct_user_id = $user->id;
                    $direct_user->save();

                    $ref_user_right = RefUser::whereNull('user_id_right')->latest('updated_at')->first();
                    $ref_user_left = RefUser::whereNull('user_id_left')->latest('updated_at')->first();

                    if($ref_user_right){
                        $ref_user_right-> user_id_right = $user->id;
                        $ref_user_right->save();
                    }else{
                        if($ref_user_left){
                            $ref_user_left-> user_id_left = $user->id;
                            $ref_user_left->save();
                        }
                        else{
                            $ref_user_right = RefUser::latest('updated_at')->first();
                            $ref_users = new RefUser();
                            $ref_users-> user_id = $ref_user_right-> user_id_right;
                            $ref_users->user_id_right = $user-> id;
                            $ref_users->save();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                $ref_users = new RefUser();
                $ref_users-> user_id = $user->id;
                $ref_users->save();
            }
```

Comment: Are you using some ORM, like Doctrine?

Comment: @Cid No, I'm not using this.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add parent_id (default=0) in the User table
2. In the User model, you need to add a relation

   ```
   protected $with = ['children'];

   public function children()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
   }
   ```

This will return the entire tree in your query.

And for showing you need a recursive method